# SQL Server 2008 Access Levels

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've 3 stored procedures -- **`SP1, SP2 & SP3.`**

**SP2** and **SP3** are called within **SP1**.

If I create a **DBRole** (and a user id) and provide the exec **access** to SP1 alone, and execute **SP1**, will **SP2 & SP3** gets executed without permission issues?

Or do we need to provide **explicit** execute access to SP2 & SP3 as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to them all, but you may use EXECUTE AS 'some other user' to gain privileges to the other procedures:

**[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

> If two objects have the same owner within a database, and one object
>   references the other, an ownership chain forms. In this case, SQL
>   Server will only check permission on the referring object. It won't
>   check permission on the referred to object.

[Example How Permissions Are Checked in a Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)